# Switching hard drives from one laptop to another

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

My dell laptop has a broken power button so I am not able to turn on my laptop. I still have warranty on the laptop so Dell wants me to send it out to them to fix it...however, there's one problem. I have some sensitive personal data saved on the laptop that I would not want to be compromised that was saved on the desktop of my old laptop. So my question is this: just to be safe, would it be possible to buy a brand new computer of the same make, model, etc, take out the hard drive from my old laptop, and put it in the new laptop, and thus transfer the data. Will the new computer boot up with the old hard drive, and will my data still be there?

Comment: Remove the hard drive, install any hard drive you have as a spare into the laptop, sent it in for repairs, when it comes back put the original drive back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... As long as you get a new laptop that is identical, or almost identical, placing the hard drive from computer A into computer B it will be as if it was computer A, except a new laptop.

Minor difference would be OK, like original had 4GB of RAM and new one has 8GB of RAM. As long as the core hardware is identical (CPU, chipsets, GPU, etc), it will work fine.

Comment: also, if it was saved on the desktop in my old laptop, is that considered also saved on the hard drive of my old laptop?

Comment: @Bob I'm not sure I understand your comment... if you swap the hard drives, it will be IDENTICAL to the old laptop, same OS, user, password, data, programs, wallpaper, etc.

Comment: oh, I see, great!

Comment: If my answer is acceptable and addresses your question, please mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: also, maybe you would know...would this likely void the warranty on the laptop?

Comment: @Bob Doubtful it would effect it unless it directly effects the warranty claim... Most manufacturers are not that granular in warranty replacement unless it is the cause of the failure. Your tallking about swapping two OEM parts from virtually identical machines.

Answer (score 0):

If the only concern is the sensitive data, you could simply buy a [sata-to-usb adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YJBL78) pull the drive on the broken computer and plug into a different computer. If the data was on your desktop you'd find the files (depending on your windows version) in c:\users[your user name]\desktop. Delete or copy them, replace the hard drive in the broken computer and send to Dell with no worries.

Comment: There are many other locations where user data is stored. Most of it is **not** on the desktop.

Comment: @DavidPostill Based on this sentence: "I have some sensitive personal data saved on the laptop that I would not want to be compromised *that was saved on the desktop* of my old laptop" I thought directions to the desktop might be helpful.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing - just pointing out that there is likely sensitive data in lots of other places. For example Chrome and Firefox passwords are not storied on the desktop, email is not stored on the desktop ... I didn't want the OP to think "I've cleared the desktop so I must be safe)"

Comment: I would image backup the whole drive to USB. Wipe the drive and restore it after the laptop comes back from repair.

Comment: @DavidPostill Good point. I hadn't thought of the possibility of other sensitive data.